# Use of toLocaleLowerCase()

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using `toLocaleLowerCase()` for the Latin characters. Latin character is "Ö". Fist I encode it then try to get the lower case of it by using `toLocaleLowerCase()`. Seems, it doesn't give me the correct lower case character

```
const encodedText: string = encodeURIComponent("Å"); --> value is "%C3%85"
const lowerCaseText: string = encodedText.toLocaleLowerCase(); --> value is "%c3%85". But it should be "%C3%A5"
```

What is the wrong here?
Is it related to browser locale?
How can I fix this?

Comment: This question seems to be related with JavaScript direcly, independent of the framework.

Comment: encodeURIComponent("Ö"); gives me  "%C3%96"

Comment: @supercool - character should be "Å". Edited the description

Comment: @yapa I updated my answer with `Å`

Comment: @IvanMontilla - Thing is this works fine if i write it using javascript. It gives me the output for _lowerCaseText_ as "%C3%A5". But it doesn't work in typescript. That is my concern .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of what you're doing is wrong.

What you want is to use `toLocaleLowerCase` first, and only then `encodeURIComponent`. Otherwise, it will change the encoded string case and not the string itself.

```js
var char = "Å";
console.log(encodeURIComponent(char));

var lowerCaseChar = char.toLocaleLowerCase();
console.log(encodeURIComponent(lowerCaseChar));
```

Comment: Yes it works in this way. But, my concern is, this works fine if i write it using java-script. It gives me the output for lowerCaseText as "%C3%A5". But it doesn't work in typescript (if I try to use toLocaleLowerCase for encoded characters)

Comment: TypeScript only adds typing to help you while writing the code. At the end it is **compiled into JavaScript**. That's why if it work in JavaScript it must work in TypeScript.